# How to save screenshot to folder using python?

Tags: python, screenshot, screen-capture, haar-classifier

I am attempting to use a Haar Cascade for object detection, and I need to take screenshots of an object across ~1000 images. Is there a way that I can screenshot a certain part of an image and have it automatically saved to a specific folder using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that. If you don't have it already installed on your machine, first you'll have to pip install it:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

After you install [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can take screenshots using the code as follows:

```py
import os
import pyautogui

save_screenshot_folder = './'

# Call pyautogui.screenshot, specifying the filepath where you want to store the screenshot.
pyautogui.screenshot(
    f'{save_screenshot_folder}{os.path.sep}SCREENSHOT_{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")}.png'
)
```

### Screenshot portion of the screen

To take a screenshot of just a portion of the screen, add the window boundaries as one of the aforementioned function parameters:

```py
import pyautogui

im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 300, 400))
```

**Hint:** to find out the exact x, and y pixel positions of the screen you want to use, `pyautogui` comes with a function that launches a widget to help you determine the mouse position:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.mouseInfo()
```

[image]

You can find additional information on how to use it [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)